# How to use conditional statements to execute (or bypass) chunks of code in Hive/SQL?

Tags: if-statement, hive, conditional-statements, hiveql

I know how to use conditional statements in Hive to assign values to variables, for example

```
CASE WHEN expression = condition1 THEN result1
     WHEN expression = condition2 THEN result2
     ...
     ELSE result
END;
```

Now I would like to use conditional statements to decide whether to execute a chunk of code. When I try to apply the above, it fails. For example,

```
CASE WHEN (expression = condition1 or expression = condition2) 
     THEN
          CREATE TABLE table1;
          CREATE TABLE table2;
          CREATE TABLE table3;
     END;
```

I get an error message `FAILED: ParseException line 5:0 cannot recognize input near 'CASE' 'WHEN' '('`.

Is it possible to use conditional statements to execute/bypass chunks of code?
Thanks!

Comment: Hive has multiple inserts functionality, e.g. `from init_table insert into first_table select ... insert into second_table select ...`, where you can use your conditions.

Comment: Hi @serge_k, thanks for the idea. I haven't been able to find any doc on this. Could you share a link detailing how to do this please?

Comment: Do you need to just create tables or insert data when conditions are met as well?

Comment: I specify a schema and a location when creating the tables so that they're filled with data at creation. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use conditional statements in Hive with DDL https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL

Comment: Thanks for the information @Harold. And I guess you don't know of a work-around?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to create empty tables then make multiple inserts, e.g.,

```
  from source_table
insert overwrite
 table first_table
select column1, column2
 where column1 = 'something'
insert overwrite
 table second_table
select column1, column2
 where column1 = 'something_else'
;
```

More info about inserts [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-InsertingdataintoHiveTablesfromqueries), about creating tables [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-CreateTableCreate/Drop/TruncateTable)